# I store my passwordstore.org data in the cloud. Are my passwords safe?

Tags: password-management

I use [pass](http://www.passwordstore.org/) to manage my passwords and sync this manually to a private git repo in the cloud.

I believe this is safe because the repo is not public and, more importantly, the data is GPG encrypted.

Am I at risk doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Am I at risk doing this?

No

If "pass" is safe, meaning it is doing encryption correctly, you could send your encrypted passwords to anyone you want and you would still be fine.

As long as they are not able to crack your master password with brute force but this might takes years if you have a strong master password.

Comment: Provided the encryption happens locally :-)

Comment: Which is indeed the case, `pass` uses GPG encryption to your (or optionally some other team members) pubkey. 
Which means that as long as your privkey is safe, the passwords should be extremely hard to crack.
And even if your privkey leaks, it should still be protected with a strong passphrase or even 2FA options.

Answer (score 6):

Pass leaks the names of the entries: if your password is named web/site.com, it will be stored in the file `~/.password-store/web/site.com.gpg`, and in the git repository it will just be `web/site.com.gpg`.

So anyone with access to your repo (in your case: github) is going be able to see the name of your passwords. This is not so great for privacy: say there is a file named `web/pornhub.com.gpg`, this might give a hint about your browsing habits ;)

Moreover, the size of the files might also gives a clue about [which accounts might have small passwords](http://lists.zx2c4.com/pipermail/password-store/2014-May/000939.html). If a file is very small, chances are that your password is small too. An attacker could use this information to select which account of yours is most likely to have a weak password.

Comment: Thanks. I'm wondering /how/ you know my repo is github ... (and whether I should admit that it isn't). ;)

Comment: You said git + cloud + private repo, and I read github. I was not even conscious I was making an assumption. Your comment made me realize you could have been using another one :)

Comment: Don't hesitate to mark it as the best answer, if you are satisfied with it ;)